# Querying data from two databases in C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I currently have a query where I am getting data from 2 different databases which is getting appended to one list called "accountbuys".

1. My first table has three data entry(3 accounts which want to buy stocks
2. The next table with 17 data points(17 stocks to buy)

I am merging these tables and getting output [image]

However,the output I want , should have 17 data points repeated each time for the 3 different accounts, so that the end user can drill down and buy whichever stock he wants[image]

PS: If what I am trying to ask is not clear, please be polite and tell me so. Please try not to be rude, I am still learning and new to StackExchange!

This is my code :`

```
public List<BuySellModel> GetBuyDataWthAccount()
{
    List<BuySellModel> accountbuys = new List<BuySellModel>();

    using (SqlConnection connectionreit = new SqlConnection(HubConnection))
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(PMConnection))

    {

        connectionhub.Open();
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command3 = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT distinct(table1.name) as 'Symbol' ,table2.Segment as 'Segment',table2.AllocationAmount as 'AllocationAmount',table2.PX_LAST as 'Price', 
                                                    table1.CUR_MKT_CAP as 'CMC',table1.FCFY_WITH_CUR_MKT_CAP as 'FCMC',table1.ROIC as 'ROIC', table1.ROICDELTA as 'ROICD' FROM View_REIT_Model_And_Holdings as table1
                                                    INNER JOIN [MostRecentlyInModelSelected] as table2
                                                        ON table1.name = table2.Ticker
                                                        WHERE table1.AllocationAmount != -1 AND
                                                        NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM [ViewPCData] as table3 WHERE table1.name = table3.Symbol AND table2.Segment = table3.SubsectorDescription AND table3.Objective = 'REITS' AND table3.SectorDescription != 'NULL' AND table3.SubsectorDescription != 'NULL')",
                                                    connectionreit);
        command3.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        SqlCommand command4 = new SqlCommand("SELECT PortfolioAccountNumber, PortfolioDescription, SUM(TotalValue) as 'TotalValue' FROM [ViewPCData] WHERE Objective = 'REITS' GROUP BY PortfolioAccountNumber,PortfolioDescription", connection);
        command4.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        var reader = command3.ExecuteReader();
        var reader1 = command4.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader1.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader1.Read())
            {
                BuySellModel accountb = new BuySellModel();
                accountb.PortfolioAccount = reader1.GetString(reader1.GetOrdinal("PortfolioAccountNumber"));
                accountb.PortfolioDescription = reader1.GetString(reader1.GetOrdinal("PortfolioDescription"));
                accountb.AccountAmount = reader1.GetDecimal(reader1.GetOrdinal("TotalValue"));
                accountbuys.Add(accountb);

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    //foreach(var account in accountbuys)
                    //{


                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        BuySellModel buy = new BuySellModel();
                        buy.Symbol = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Symbol"));
                        buy.Segment = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Segment"));
                        //if (accountNumber == "soand os")
                        //{
                        //    1/3 of totalaccountvalue
                        buy.AllocationAmount = (reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("AllocationAmount")));
                        //}
                        buy.Price = reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("Price"));
                        buy.MarketValue = reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("CMC"));
                        buy.FCFY = reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("FCMC"));
                        buy.ROIC = reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("ROIC"));
                        buy.ROICdelta = reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("ROICD"));
                        buy.Buy = true;
                        //account1 = account.accountnumber;                   
                        accountbuys.Add(buy);

                    }
                    //} //for loop


                }


            } // accounts
        } //reader1.hasrows

        connectionhub.Close();
        connection.Close();
    }

    return accountbuys;
}
```

EDIT:

Split the tables into two different lists and merged them later. This is working well now. Seems good for scaling too.

```
public List<BuySellModel> GetBuyDataWthAccount()
    {
        List<BuySellModel> accountbuys = new List<BuySellModel>();

        List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();


        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(PMConnection))

        {

            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand command3 = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT distinct(table1.name) as 'Symbol' ,table2.Segment as 'Segment',table2.AllocationAmount as 'AllocationAmount',table2.PX_LAST as 'Price', 
                                                table1.CUR_MKT_CAP as 'CMC',table1.FCFY_WITH_CUR_MKT_CAP as 'FCMC',table1.ROIC as 'ROIC', table1.ROICDELTA as 'ROICD' FROM View_Model_And_Holdings as table1
                                                INNER JOIN [MostRecentlyInModelSelected] as table2
                                                    ON table1.name = table2.Ticker
                                                    WHERE table1.AllocationAmount != -1 AND
                                                    NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM [ViewPCData] as table3 WHERE table1.name = table3.Symbol AND table2.Segment = table3.SubsectorDescription AND table3.Objective = 'STOCKS' AND table3.SectorDescription != 'NULL' AND table3.SubsectorDescription != 'NULL')",
                                                connectionreit);
          command3.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

          SqlCommand command4 = new SqlCommand("SELECT PortfolioDetail , SUM(TotalValue) as 'TotalValue' FROM [ViewPCData] WHERE Objective = 'STOCKS' GROUP BY PortfolioAccountNumber,PortfolioDescription", connection);
          command4.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            var reader = command3.ExecuteReader();
            var reader1 = command4.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader1.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader1.Read())
                {
                    Account accountb = new Account();
                    accountb.PortfolioDetail = reader1.GetString(reader1.GetOrdinal("PortfolioDetail"));
                   // accountb.PortfolioDescription = reader1.GetString(reader1.GetOrdinal("PortfolioDescription"));
                    accountb.AccountAmount = reader1.GetDecimal(reader1.GetOrdinal("TotalValue"));

                    accounts.Add(accountb);
                }
            }
            //List<BuyReits> buys = new List<BuyReits>();
            if (reader.HasRows && accounts.Count > 0)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    foreach (var acc in accounts)
                    {
                        BuySellModel buy = new BuySellModel();
                        buy.Symbol = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Symbol"));
                        buy.Segment = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Segment"));
                        buy.AllocationAmount = (reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("AllocationAmount")));
                        buy.Price = reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("Price"));
                        //buy.Quantity = reader.GetInt32((reader.GetOrdinal("AllocationAmount"))/(reader.GetOrdinal("Price")));
                        buy.MarketValue = reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("CMC"));
                        buy.FCFY = reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("FCMC"));
                        buy.ROIC = reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("ROIC"));
                        buy.ROICdelta = reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("ROICD"));
                        buy.Buy = true;
                        buy.PortfolioAccount = acc.PortfolioDetail;
                        buy.AccountAmount = acc.AccountAmount;

                        accountbuys.Add(buy);

                    }

                }
            }

            connection.Close();


        }

        return accountbuys;

    }
```

Comment: Are you using mysql or sql server? They are not the same thing. Also, it would be very helpful if you posted some details about your tables. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: It is commonly asked that you state exactly what is not working in your current code.  Also you have tags for both mysql and sql-server and it is generally asked that you choose one.

Comment: Is not very clear what is not working. What's the issue?

Comment: @SeanLange Thank you for the link! That is helpful.

Comment: SmithaShivakumar - what version of .Net are you using? Do you have access to the LINQ libraries?

Comment: @JoeC Thank you for pointing it out! I changed it now. I am using Sql Server

Comment: @Forty3 I am using 2015 version. I should have LINQ

Comment: @AdrianIftode I have edited the question, am sorry for not being clear before.

Answer (score 3):

The following provides the cross join in the C# layer (not saying it is the best possible solution, but it gets you closer to ready):

```
using (SqlConnection connectionhub = new SqlConnection(HubConnection))
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(PMConnection))

{

    connectionhub.Open();
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand command3 = new SqlCommand(@"
        SELECT distinct(table1.name) as 'Symbol',
               table2.Segment as 'Segment',
               table2.AllocationAmount as 'AllocationAmount',
               table2.PX_LAST as 'Price', 
               table1.CUR_MKT_CAP as 'CMC',
               table1.FCFY_WITH_CUR_MKT_CAP as 'FCMC',
               table1.ROIC as 'ROIC', 
               table1.ROICDELTA as 'ROICD' 
          FROM View_REIT_Model_And_Holdings as table1
                INNER JOIN [MostRecentlyInModelSelected] as table2
                    ON table1.name = table2.Ticker
         WHERE table1.AllocationAmount != -1 
           AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
                             FROM [ViewPCData] as table3 
                            WHERE table1.name = table3.Symbol 
                              AND table2.Segment = table3.SubsectorDescription 
                              AND table3.Objective = 'REITS' 
                              AND table3.SectorDescription != 'NULL' 
                              AND table3.SubsectorDescription != 'NULL')",
                                                connectionreit);
    command3.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    SqlCommand command4 = new SqlCommand(@"
        SELECT PortfolioAccountNumber, 
               PortfolioDescription, 
               SUM(TotalValue) as 'TotalValue' 
          FROM [ViewPCData] 
         WHERE Objective = 'REITS' 
         GROUP BY PortfolioAccountNumber, PortfolioDescription", connection);
    command4.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    var stocksDS = new DataSet();
    var stocksDA = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter();
    stocksDA.SelectCommand = command3
    stocksDA.Fill(stocksDS, "stocks");

    var acctsDS = new DataSet();
    var acctsDA = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter();
    acctsDA.SelectCommand = command4
    acctsDA.Fill(acctsDS, "accts");

    var stocks = stocksDS.Tables["stocks"].AsEnumerable();
    var accts = acctsDS.Tables["accts"].AsEnumerable();

    var results = (from stocksDR in stocks
                   from acctsDR in accts
                   select new BuySellModel {
                        PortfolioAccount = acctsDR["PortfolioAccountNumber"],
                        PortfolioDescription = acctsDR["PortfolioAccountDescription"],
                        AccountAmount = acctsDR["TotalValue"],
                        Symbol = stocksDR["Symbol"],
                        Segment = stocksDR["Segment"],
                        AllocationAmount = stocksDR["AllocationAmount"],
                        Price = stocksDR["Price"],
                        MarketValue = stocksDR["CMC"],
                        FCFY = stocksDR["FCMC"],
                        ROIC = stocksDR["ROIC"],
                        ROICdelta = stocksDR["ROICD"],
                        Buy = true
                    });

    foreach (BySellModel buy in results) {
        accountBuys.Add(buy);
    }

    connectionhub.Close();
    connection.Close();
}
```

Edit: removed offending parentheses.

Comment: Thank you for this! I am getting an error that "An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code" Am I missing something? I do have the "ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings"  setup..

Comment: What line is it reporting the error on? Also, did you add `using System.Data.DataSetExtensions;` to the top of the file? You may need to add a reference to the DLL to your project, too.

Comment: It is giving me that error to the entire block of "select new BuySellModel()" towards the end of var results. 

It also gives this - "Additional information: Column 'PortfolioAccountDescription' does not belong to table accts."

Comment: And the "using System.Data.DataSetExtensions" is not accepted by my code, it says DataExtensions doesn't exist in System.Data

Comment: To get DataSetExtensions available, you will need to find and add a reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll within your project. As for the error with `select new BuySellModel()` I may have been overeager and you cannot select a static type from the linq query - try it without the () after BuySellModel.

Comment: I did that, thank you!! I am still trying to fix my other error with the System.Data dll

Comment: @ForeverLearner - what is the error, exactly? And on what line of code?

Answer (score 0):

Without changing any of your C# code, it may be possible to get what you want by changing the SQL query from an INNER JOIN query to a CROSS JOIN query.

Some caveats regarding this approach though:

1. If you include a WHERE clause, the query will act as an INNER JOIN.
2. Cross joins can be significantly slower, as the query is looking to make all possible combinations.  With only 51 (3 * 17) combinations available that will not be a significant issue, but if you are looking to scale this to more clients and stocks, it will become increasingly worse performance wise

Comment: Yea I am looking to scale as I could potentially have more clients.