# ASP.NET Core Web API - implement multiple databases using Sybase and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, sybase

For some days now I've been trying to implement multiple databases in ASP.NET Core-6 Web API using Sybase and SQL Server. I have never done this before.

I have this connection:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MssqlDbConnection": "Server=nikatic;Database=mymssql;Trusted_Connection=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true;",
    "SybaseDbConnection": "Server=nxppawe;Database=mysybase;Port=6645;Min Pool Size=100;Max Pool Size=1000;User ID=acme;Password=lennon;charset=cp850;"
  },
```

I have three (3) tables:

1. Employees  ---> From SQL Server
2. EmployeeProject  --> Sybase
3. Projects  --> Sybase

I want to query the 3 tables from the two different databases and display the result.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

var sql = @"select e.EmployeeId, e.Name, e.StaffNo, e.Gender, e.DateOfBirth, p.ProjectId, p.Name, p.Duration
            from Employees e
            inner join
            EmployeeProject ep on ep.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
            inner join 
            Projects p on p.ProjectId = ep.ProjectId;";
```

How do I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: You don't have a direct way. You will have to query each Table from each DB and bring it as lists in code behind and than you can use LINQ to perform the wanted join. You have a similar example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43458171/querying-data-from-two-databases-in-c-sharp

Comment: Use linked servers. Then no matter Sybase or SQL Server is becomes a local database to the server you are running on.

Comment: @access_granted - How do you mean by linked servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a link for you to create a linked server from SQL Server to ASE 12

https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/sybase-odbc-linked-server.rst

General doc on how to create a linked server in SSMS

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Once you created it, you will be able to access any of your Sybase tables from SQL Server. Note the 4-name notation for remote tables vs 3-name notation for local tables.

```
select 
  e.EmployeeId, e.Name, e.StaffNo, e.Gender, e.DateOfBirth, p.ProjectId, p.Name, p.Duration 
from 
  nxppawe.mysybase.acme.Projects p
join nxppawe.mysybase.acme.EmployeeProject ep 
  on p.ProjectId = ep.ProjectId
join mymssql.dbo.Employees e 
  on ep.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
;
```

Comment: access_granted - Which nugget package do you recommend I use for the Sybase?

Comment: if we are talking about NuGet, then there's not too many to choose from. Try aceryansoft.sqlflow if you plan to switch between databases a lot.